# Twig get data from array

Tags: twig

I recently asked a question about how I could convert the following to Twig

```
$firstDate = array_pop(array_keys($dates));
```

After being suggested to use the slice filter, I worked on it for a while and came up with something that appears to do the job

```
{% set firstDate = (dates|keys)|last %}
```

Now I have another problem.  I essentially have to do the following in Twig

```
foreach (array_keys($dates[$firstDate]) as $classLetter) {
```

I have made a horrible effort to do this, but it doesnt seem to like the []

```
{% for dates[firstDate]|keys in classLetter %}
```

Is there anyway I can do something like the above PHP code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After spending a while on it, came up with a solution

```
{% for classLetter in attribute(dates, firstDate)|keys %}
```